# Apache CXF :: wsdl2java ignoring catalog configuration for public entries

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I am using Apache CXF 2.7.6 `wsdl2java` and it seems that the tool ignores or fails to find public catalog entries. In particular I have the following `<xs:import>` in one of my XSD files:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCcoords/v1.10"/>
```

The above cannot be properly resolved with the catalog file entry:

```
<public publicId="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCcoords/v1.10" uri="STCcoords-v1.10.xsd"/>
```

If I change the `<xs:import>` by adding a `schemaLocation` attribute, i.e. change it to:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCcoords/v1.10" schemaLocation="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/STC/STCcoords/v1.10/>
```

It resolves files, but my understanding is that this shouldn't have been necessary as I don't want to have to edit the XSD I am provided with.

The behavior is the same whether OASIS XML format or TR9401 format is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reply I got from the **Apache CXF** users mailing list is that the XML Schema specification leaves this point up to the implementation and so is not considered a bug.

Thread [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201309.mbox/browser) (the post is dated September 26th 2013, is on page 2 and I don't seem to be able to provide a link directly to that page). The relevant conclusion is [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201309.mbox/%3CB3B7D475-EE39-4C57-B54E-381D785E8B02@apache.org%3E). I quote:

> My thoughts on this:
>
> 1) According to the schema spec, if the schemaLocation hint isn't
>   specified, it's up to the application to figure out how to resolve it
>   if needed.   Thus, I don't really consider this a "bug".   We
>   specifically just  use the information provided and is part of the
>   "compilation unit" (aka: wsdl).
>
> 2) Personally, I think it's pretty silly to NOT provide the
>   schemaLocation and would STRONGLY STRONGLY recommend adding it.  The
>   only time I've ever seen it not specified is when importing schemas
>   that are also embedded in the same wsdl (so there isn't a location).
>   When ever I see things like "up to the application" in specs, that, to
>   me, is an interoperability nightmare.   Just specify it.
>
> 3) That all said, the root issue would be in XmlSchema's SchemaBuilder
>   class.  If there isn't a schemaLocation, it assumes it's part of the
>   compilation unit it's working on and continues.   Doesn't try to
>   resolve anything.   If you want to pursue a patch or something, it
>   would be around 680 of SchemaBuilder.java.  But even changing that MAY
>   require more support from CXF's side to pre-populate the namespaces it
>   already knows to  avoid it going off to the internet for them.   Not
>   really sure.

So, it is confirmed that:

- the default `wsimport` tool that ships with *Oracle Java 7* **does** use a catalog to resolve an **import** statement even without a **schemaLocation** attribute.
- the Apache CXF 2.7.6 `wsdl2java` tool **does not** use a catalog to resolve an **import** statement without a **schemaLocation** attribute
- the Apache CXF community does not view this as a bug.